# How to make the browser full screen mode in a Samsung Galaxy Tab A device?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, google-chrome

I have a plain html website and I want to display it in a Galaxy Tab A 10 in full screen mode, as the user moves around the pages.
I got close to that with 'Fully Kiosk Browser & App Lockdown', but it breaks the design.
Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: I've added a full screen toggle to a site before, with [requestFullScreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen)

Comment: yes, but as the user moves around the pages the full screen goes away, and I want to keep the full screen during navigation

Comment: If all the navigation is on your own site, you can deal with that by either capturing link clicks and handling it using XHR or fetch; or you could add an iframe. Make the iframe full screen, and navigate inside that. But if you're navigating multiple sites that might not work so well.